# bootstrap datepicker: the arrow icons are not visible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I use bootstrap for the datepicker , the problem is that the arrow is not visble for next and previous month, as soon as I try to edit any CSS property of DOM side on Chrome, it works, it's like I did a refresh DOM . by against IE and firefox, the icons are visible.